# Java, синхронизация времени

Tags: java

Поставлена задача: каждую секунду *в соответствии с системным временем* выполнять определённое действие. Я сделал таймер на 1000мс с действием. Однако, как теперь связать его с системным временем? Чтобы, когда у системного времени был переход от одной секунды к другой - четко срабатывал таймер, и что-то делал?
Простой пример - выводить текущее время в консоль:

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
          {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + 
                        calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
          }
        );
timer1.start();
```

В среднем системное время опережает таймер на 0.5 - 0.7 секунд. Ниже показано видео, где виден вывод в консоль и текущее системное время.
[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Kxz8Lew4k&feature=youtu.be)
Как настроить идеальную синхронизацию?(в системном времени секунда переключилась и в это же время вывелась новая строка в терминал с новым значением)

Comment: Невозможно сделать это точно, разве что в системе есть коллбэки на изменение времени (однако в яве я о таком не слышал). Если вас устраивает точность в 10-100 мс, то вполне себе можно гонять поток в цикле со слипом в 10-100 мс. Попробую сейчас вам тестик набросать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот возможный вариант решения проблемы:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    while (true) {
        int ms = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        Thread.sleep(1000 - ms);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

Насколько я мог подметить, запаздывает где-то на 100 мс. Очевидно, из-за абстракций между системой и софтом.

Если нужно запустить это как таймер - сделайте в новом потоке:

```
Thread timerThread = new Thread(() -> {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int ms = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
            Thread.sleep(1000 - ms);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Timer thread was interrupted");
    }
});
timerThread.start();
```

Не забудьте, прервать выполнение такого таймера можно так:

```
timerThread.interrupt();
```

Если вы закончили выполнять другой код и хотите присоединиться к потоку таймера:

```
timerThread.join()
```

(Кстати, если вы это не сделаете и завершите программу, то у вас появятся зомбики в системе, хех). Шучу, конечно. Но все же стоит ждать все потоки, или же прерывать их, а не надеяться, что все за вас потом сделает `jvm`.

Для `Java 7` и меньше:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         ....   
    }
};
```

В своем примере я усыпляю поток на количество миллисикунд, по прошествии которых секунд станет на 1 больше.

Ваше решение с таймером можно запустить в тот момент, когда сменяется секунда. Однако в этом мало смысла, ибо на каждом интервале погрешность будет накапливаться, и уже через пару десятков миллисекунд может наблюдаться значительная рассинхронизация.

С моим же подходом погрешность будет практически константная (+-). Кстати, если вас не устраивает небольшое "запаздывание" такого таймера, то вы можете заставить поток спать чуть меньше положенного времени, но (как мне кажется) в этом нет особого смысла.

Надеюсь, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Это именно то, что нужно! Подстроил для себя, и система теперь работает, как "часы". Огромное спасибо! :)

Comment: @Range хахах, а вопрос "для чего это все же нужно" так и останется нераскрытым...)

Comment: Ох, я его не заметил. Делаю будильник, связанный с системным временем. В нм есть анимация, она также связана с системным временем. Как-то так:)

Comment: @Range а, такого вопроса и не было) просто мне вдруг любопытно стало. Ну удачи там с кодом)

Comment: Весьма! Теперь всё прям красиво и аккуратно, еще раз спасибо)